# Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\OCI8\Connection::_prepare()

Tags: oracle, codeigniter-4

I am using Codeigniter 4 with Oracle. Inside my controller, I have this code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {

        $this->db = \Config\Database::connect();
        

        $query = "select * from test";

        $this->db->_prepare($query);
        $this->db->_execute();
        

        echo "<table border='1'>\n";
        $ncols =$this->db->getFieldCount();
        echo "<tr>\n";
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $ncols; ++$i) {
            $colname = $this->db->getFieldNames($s, $i);
            echo "  <th><b>".htmlspecialchars($colname,ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE)."</b></th>\n";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";

        while (($row = $this->db->fetchAssoc()) != false) {
            echo "<tr>\n";
            foreach ($row as $item) {
                echo "<td>";
                echo $item!==null?htmlspecialchars($item, ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE):"&nbsp;";
                echo "</td>\n";
            }
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
        echo "</table>\n";

    }
}
```

This code is returning an error: `Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\OCI8\Connection::_prepare()`

the method CodeIgniter\Database\OCI8\Connection is returning the oci_connect result

How could I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Error:

```bash
Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\OCI8\Connection::_prepare()
```

##### Explanation:

The error above is pretty clear. You're trying to call the `_prepare(...)` method which ***doesn't*** exist in the [`CodeIgniter\Database\OCI8\Connection`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/c0b9928bc7dc983f7914f379795197ee7410db1a/system/Database/OCI8/Connection.php#L24) class.

##### Solution:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Database\Query;

class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $db = db_connect();

        // Prepare the Query
        $preparedQuery = $db->prepare(static function ($db) {
            return (new Query($db))->setQuery('SELECT * FROM test WHERE 1=?');
        });

        $resultInterface = $preparedQuery->execute(1);
        $preparedQuery->close();

        $fieldNames = $resultInterface->getFieldNames();
        $fieldCount = $resultInterface->getFieldCount();
        $resultSet = $resultInterface->getResultArray();

        echo "<table border='1'>\n";

        echo "<tr>\n";
        foreach ($fieldNames as $fieldName) {
            echo "  <th><b>"
                . htmlspecialchars(
                    $fieldName,
                    ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE
                )
                . "</b></th>\n";

        }
        echo "</tr>\n";

        foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
            echo "<tr>\n";

            foreach (range(0, $fieldCount - 1) as $fieldIndex) {
                echo "<td>";
                echo !empty($row[$fieldNames[$fieldIndex]])
                    ? htmlspecialchars(
                        $row[$fieldNames[$fieldIndex]],
                        ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE
                    )
                    : "&nbsp;";
                echo "</td>\n";

            }
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }

         echo "</table>\n";

    }
}
```

[Preparing the Query](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#preparing-the-query)

> This can be easily done with the `prepare()` method. This takes a
> single parameter, which is a Closure that returns a query object.
> Query objects are automatically generated by any of the *“final”* type
> queries, including **insert, update, delete, replace,** and **get**.
> This is handled the easiest by using the Query Builder to run a query.
> The query is not actually run, and the values don’t matter since
> they’re never applied, acting instead as placeholders. This returns a
> `PreparedQuery` object:

> If you don’t want to use the Query Builder you can create the Query
> object manually using question marks for value placeholders:

[Executing the Query](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#executing-the-query)

> Once you have a prepared query you can use the `execute()` method to
> actually run the query. You can pass in as many variables as you need
> in the query parameters. The number of parameters you pass must match
> the number of placeholders in the query. They must also be passed in
> the same order as the placeholders appear in the original query:

[getFieldCount()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#getfieldcount)

> The number of FIELDS (columns) returned by the query. Make sure to
> call the method using your query result object:

[getFieldNames()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#getfieldnames)

> Returns an array with the names of the FIELDS (columns) returned by
> the query. Make sure to call the method using your query result
> object: